# Android location change Latitude and Longitude from DMS format to double

Tags: android, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude

I have this format for a location (*24°13'30.92"N*,*55°45'51.94"E*) and I need to convert it through android to a double value like (*24.225275*, *55.764417*).

I tried something like this and it did not work

```
String lonStr="24°13'30.92"N";
Double lon=Location.convert(lonStr);
```

Comment: the value are in `degree,minute ,second ` and direction

Comment: yes I know and I want to convert it to a double value

Comment: in your `onLocationChange(Location location)` just access `location.getLongitude()` and `location.getLatitude()`

Comment: `substring` and `indexOf` will help you check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `substring` and `indexOf`
>
> extract **minutes** and **second** divide by **60** and **3600** respectively and
>   finally add **degree** part.

```
    String str="24°13'30.92\"N,55°45'51.94\"E";

    String s[]=str.split(",");
    double lat=Integer.parseInt(s[0].substring(0,s[0].indexOf("°")))+(double)Integer.parseInt(s[0].substring(s[0].indexOf("°")+1, s[0].indexOf("'")))/60+ Double.parseDouble(s[0].substring(s[0].indexOf("'")+1, s[0].indexOf("\"")))/3600;

  // same for longitude
   System.out.println(String.format("%.6f", lat));
```

output:

```
24.225256
```